# Adding points to osm file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, editing, pbf

I have downloaded an osm file from Geofabrik download server and opened this `.osm.pbf`-file in QGIS. So there are 5 classes - lines, multiline strings, multipolygons, other_relations, and points.

I wanted to add some additional number of points and give them attributes in this vector layer. And finally, save it as `.osm.pbf` again, As I need the `.osm.pbf` for osmosis.

Is there a method to do the same? As editing in that layer is not happening.